# Dynamic MapPin image not scaling correctly IOS 8 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uiimageview, mapkit

Hello all so i'm working with mapkit, iOS 8, and swift and I'm using custom map pins to display the annotation view.

I'm pulling the map data from server etc. and i have a property that tell me wether to display the custom map pin or a regular map pin that's a part of map kit.

I added an extension to MKannotationview that asynchronously loads the image from an NSURL and that works just fine. I use the similar extension for uiimageview for my tableviews and async loading.

If i have the image asset (Map pin) stored locally in the image assets folder it results with the map pin on the map as expected with correct dimensions and no distortion etc.

[image: Normal map pin from image stored locally on device]

The problem is when i download the exact same image from my server and set that image, it is larger than the one stored in the image assets and it is distorted.

[image: Distorted image from server]

So know you guys & gals know my problem. Again they are both the same image with the same size  and dimensions 50x82 with 72 dpi.

Things i have tried: I thought it might be an IOS thing with Images being 2x etc. so i cut the dimensions in half from the image coming from the server to 25x41 and that didn't help. I also thought it might have a point issue and not a pixel issue. so i changed the points to be half the resolution and doubled the dpi.

Sadly none of that helped i was still getting the distorted images. I want it to be dynamic because during different seasons and holidays i want to be able to change the theme of the map pin without making the user update the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i figured it out. the image was 2x the scale i needed it to be (obvious) so i had to scale it down using graphics context (redraw it) so just using the retuned image from server you can see how its done.

```
        let newSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width/2.0, height: image.size.height/2.0)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)

        image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: newSize))

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            self.image = scaledImage
        })
```